# How to mock axios and test without using third party lib in a correct way in react vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, axios

I am testing a custom hook in React Vite where I am using Axios simply not `Vitest` or `axios-mock-adapter`. and I know that API shouldn't be called with a real endpoint while testing or it should be better to mock it correct me if I'm wrong. So the problem is when I mock axios, even not knowing the correct way to mock them. I'm not sure if testing is going well or not, it feels like the way I want to test that's not happening and I'm doing something wrong.

What I did so far like this in custom hook (useFetch.js)

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useFetch = (options, ref, initialvalue) => {
    const [news, setNews] = useState(initialvalue);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        if (ref.current) {
            const sleep = (s) =>
                new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, s * 1000));
            (async () => {
                try {
                    await sleep(10);
                    const res = await axios.request(options);
                    setNews(res.data.articles);
                } catch (err) {
                    setError(err.message);
                } finally {
                    await sleep(30);
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            })();
        }

        return () => {
            ref.current = false;
        };
    }, [options, ref]);

    return {
        loading,
        news,
        error,
        setNews
    };
};
```

I want to know if my custom hook is correct or not because when I tried to
do like this in my test code

```
import { renderHook, act, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useFetch } from "../hooks/useFetch.js";
import axios from "axios";

const articles = [
    {
        title:
            "ARK reduziert Anteile: Cathie Wood wirft Tesla-Aktien aus dem Depot",

        excerpt:
            "• ARK Invest verkauft Tesla-Anteile im Wert von 43,7 Millionen US-Dollar • Tesla-Aktie bleibt Top-Holding in drei ETFs • Cathie Wood sieht Tesla-Aktie falsch ...",

        _id: "e3c5e3a88c985a015b6051812198670d"
    }
];

const newsUrl = `${process.env.TEST_NEWS_API_ENDPOINT}/search`;

describe("useFetch", () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    test("fetches successfully data from an API", async () => {
        // Mock axios API
        const axiosGetSpy = jest
            .spyOn(axios, "request")
            .mockResolvedValueOnce(articles); //when I mock like this

        // Execute
        const { result } = renderHook(() =>
            useFetch(newsUrl, { current: true }, articles) // here `articles` should be an empty array as intialvalue but I did like this to get pass that's really embracing for me! then what should I do here?
        );


        expect(result.current.error).toBe(null);

        await waitFor(() => {
            act(() => {
                expect(result.current).toEqual({
                    loading: true,
                    news: articles,
                    error: null,
                    setNews: result.current.setNews
                });
            });
        });

        axiosGetSpy.mockRestore();
    });

    test("should catch error", async () => {
        const axiosGetSpy = jest
            .spyOn(axios, "request")
            .mockRejectedValueOnce("error occured");
        
        // below two lines code is correct? or how to do this?
        expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith(newsUrl); 
        expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

        const { result } = renderHook(() =>
            useFetch(newsUrl, { current: true }, [])
        );

        await waitFor(() => {
            act(() => {
                expect(result.current).toEqual({
                    loading: false,
                    news: [],
                    error: new Error("error occured"),
                    setNews: result.current.setNews
                });
            });
        });

        axiosGetSpy.mockRestore();
    });
});
```

and test show me like this

```
// TEST 1 (earlier)

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 2
    + Received  + 2

      Object {
    -   "error": [Error: error occured],
    -   "loading": false,
    +   "error": null,
    +   "loading": true,
        "news": Array [],
        "setNews": [Function bound dispatchSetState],
     }

// TEST 2 (now)
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "https://url.com/v2/search"

    Number of calls: 0

      55 |             .mockRejectedValueOnce("error occured");
      56 |
    > 57 |         expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith(newsUrl);   
         |                               ^
      58 |         expect(axios.request).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);        
      59 |
      60 |         const { result } = renderHook(() =>
```

*And my both testing is not correct I think cause when I tried to change (cheating) something to get passed then it shows pass but that's really wrong!! I'm following  this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/testing-a-custom-react-hook-21ae732228b7) from starting point of how to create custom hook for fetching data*

**UPDATE:**

`@testing-library/react-hooks` should use this? cause it is maybe going to deprecated due to [this](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library#a-note-about-react-18-support)

I got to know after a lot time that **I didn't mock axios correctly and it is not calling my custom hook even more. and that's why I am getting initial value of my custom hook can some one tell me how to proprly mock it? How to do that?**

If someone look on to my code I'd be grateful!

Comment: I got to know after a lot time I didn't mock axios correctly and it is not calling my custom hook even more. and **that's why I am getting initial value of my custom hook**

can some one tell me how to proprly mock it? How to do that?